# How to share Library files/ include folders between projects in a single solution on Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, directory-structure

I have a VS solution with two separate projects, but I would like to share the external libraries between them. How would I go about this? Let's say I have two projects in one Solution on Visual Studio Code:

Solution
Project A
Project B

I have already included the external libraries on Project A, but I want those libraries to be linked to all my projects within the solution, so I don't have to include them again every time I make a new project.

I tried including all the libraries on one project but the other project couldn't access the library like I was expecting. So I had to manually include the libraries for both, bot I want to avoid this to save myself some time.

Comment: I suppose you could add `#pragma comment( lib, "librarypathname" )` to one of the header files.

Comment: I feel like you'd have to make a third library that they both depend on, then make sure its transitive dependencies are linked onto its users.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the program to work, it is necessary to manually add the library. But in order to reduce repetitive work, you could create a project template after adding the library, and use this template directly when creating a new project without adding the library again.

About how to create a project template you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022#use-the-export-template-wizard).

After the project template is created, you could directly search for it.

[image]